# What exactly is a microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, integrated-circuit, mouse

Can an optical mouse sensor chip (System On Chip) which has a digital signal processor, Serial I/O, and a set of registers be considered as a Micro-controller?

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/116903/is-a-computer-mouse-considered-an-embedded-system/116904#116904

Answer (score 3):

IMHO As long as they have a CPU, memory, peripheral units and are programmable can be considered as micro-controller. But as *captcha* mentioned today most of them are a not programmable or so little programmable-configurable that only let companies to vary their products with little tricks.

Comment: For it to be a micro*controller*, and not a microprocessor, it should have some physical world interfacing (analog or digital) as well as the things you mention.

Answer (score 1):

It probably started out as one in the development stage but I guess that nowadays these chips are purpose-built chips that are far less flexible than the average micro is. To answer your question.. No.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. There are many dedicated ICs which are not specially built parts, but really generic controllers with specific programming. Anything with a 8051 core is one example. Or a more specific example is MicroChips mcp2000 (p/n?) Usb to serial IC. Its well known to be a PIC18fxxxx, a usb capable microcontroller with Microchips USB to Serial firmware, but licensed for general use. It even registers as a pic when hooked up to a pic programmer.

But would you call it a microcontroller? Technically, it is. In practice and marketing, it is not. You would not reflash it with custom software, and will always cost more than a blank mcu.